# Add-Migration command not working error 0x80073D54

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, uwp

I created an application by https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/03/data-access-in-universal-windows-platform-uwp-apps/#LTm66jG1JvVVXDxi.97

But command **Add-Migration MyFirstMigration** does not work.
Do you know why

```
PM> Add-Migration MyFirstMigration
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: **The process does not contain the identity of the package (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073D54)**
   at Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.get_Current()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.GetApplicationData()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.AdjustForRelativeDirectory(String path)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute[T](IRelationalConnection connection, Func`3 action, String executeMethod, Boolean openConnection, Boolean closeConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteScalar(IRelationalConnection connection, Boolean manageConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.Internal.SqliteDatabaseCreator.HasTables()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.RelationalDatabaseCreator.EnsureCreated()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated()
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue. My environment information are as follows：Visual Studio 2015 update 3, windows 10 SDK 14393, UWP target version 14393,min version 10586.

But according to your exception stack details, error is occurred at `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.get_Current()`.  It seems Add-Migration  operation wants to visit your app's local folder, but there is no local folder currently since the app is not deployed.

Add-Migration will instantiate your `DbContext` class, which retrieves the value of `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path` in order to build the connection string. Since it's being invoked from VS, it seems it fails due to the lack of package identifier that's provided when running in the context of a Windows Store app.

So please try to deploy your app or run it firstly to ensure the local folder is existed. If the local folder has been created, but the exception still exist,  you can hard code the detail connection string like follows instead of only a DB file name `Sensors.db`(The OnConfiguring method is in the model class). The folder name `61bbd292-ef8c-4a2e-b0c4-360dd2335d4d_9889v3km7snsp` in the following code is the  package family name of your app and you can find in `Package.mainfest`->`Packaging`.

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
 {
     var connection = @"Filename=C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Packages\61bbd292-ef8c-4a2e-b0c4-360dd2335d4d_9889v3km7snsp\LocalState\Sensors.db";
     optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connection);
 }
```

More details please reference the floor 7 in [issue1058](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1058) of Entity Framework.